# Copy the file created newly in UNIX

Tags: shell-script

I have a directory where so many files created daily and need to copy the new files which were generated. And all files will be created with starting name abc_ 
Ex:I have a file  abc_0520123.pdf on the next day two files were created abc_0521234.pdf and abc_0521254.pdf now I want to copy only these two files created newly.
Please help me how can I compare old files with new one and to copy them.

Comment: It is unclear to me. Is there any logic in the filenames? Or you want to copy every file created in the past 24h?

Comment: I need to copy the files which are created newly. If the file already has been copied it should not be copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU find:

```
find . -type f -newermt "today 00:00" -exec echo {} +
```

If you want to handle only those files whose name begins with `abc_` then:

```
find . -type f -name 'abc_*' -newermt "today 00:00" -exec echo {} +
```

Of course, you would finally do something different from `echo`, e.g.

```
find . -type f -newermt "today 00:00" -exec mv --target-directory=/move/here {} +
```

Comment: when i use this command i am getting error like
"find: 0652-017 -newrmt is not a valid option"

Comment: @user2910201 Obviously you have not always used copy and paste as it is `-newermt` in my code but `-newrmt` in your comment...